# Cannot save a workbook containing charts generated with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Using Microsoft Excel 2013

In an empty new workbook, I can run successfull this macro :

```
Sub ReproduceError()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Ch As Chart

    Set Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set Ch = Sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

End Sub
```

But when I'm trying to save the workbook, I receive this error :

> Errors where detected while saving [file name]. Microsoft Excel may be
>   able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make
>   the repairs in a new file, click Continue. To cancel saving the file,
>   click Cancel.

Comment: Can somebody tell me if it is the same by him ?

Comment: If you go ahead and make the repairs, what repairs are listed as having been made? Do you get the same error message if saving as an XLSB binary workbook?

Comment: The repair dialog says that it can't repair the file. It's the same with a xlsb file.

I think it comes from a default template for charts installed by my company, but I don't know how to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried defining the range that the chart is to occupy?

```
Range("A10:B14").Select 
sh.Shapes.AddChart.Select
```

Comment: That's it. Without that, there is no source binded to the Chart, even if data is added with "SeriesCollections.NewSeries".